# PHP: How to get line from txt and dont repeat

Tags: php

Hello im using a multithread class to get emails from a list

using `file_get_contents("http://server.com/getemails.php");`

this is *getemails.php*:

```
index = file("index.dat");
$index = $index[0];
$f_contents = file("../susc/ar.txt");
$line = $f_contents[$index];
$data = $line;

file_put_contents("index.dat",$index +1);

echo $data;
```

it gets data from "../susc/ar.txt" 
that file has 100.000 lines with like this :

```
sampleuser@hotmail.com
suscribeduser@hotmail.com
exampleemail@hotmail.com
...
```

but, when i run my program multithreaded .. gives a lot of repeated emails

like this:

```
[Thread][t11] -> sampleuser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t12] -> sampleuser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t8] -> sampleuser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t1] -> sampleuser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t2] -> sampleuser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t5] -> suscribeduser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t3] -> suscribeduser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t6] -> suscribeduser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t7] -> suscribeduser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t4] -> suscribeduser@hotmail.com

[Thread][t14] -> exampleemail@hotmail.com

[Thread][t9] -> exampleemail@hotmail.com

[Thread][t10] -> exampleemail@hotmail.com
```

My question is, what method i can use to get a line from the text file and dont repeat on next request

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to accomplish this using multiple threads? The reason why you are getting repeated values is because each thread is reading the same data from the top of the file.

Comment: @pseudoh is right. You should limit the number of messagens each thread will handle and then inform each thread where to start working. IE: suppose each thread will handle 100 messages and die, so first thread starts at 0, the second begin at position 100 and so on... this should solve your problem... but who/what is going to solve the problem of the people will receive this huge amount of emails??

Comment: @pseudoh, is because i need to process the list fast , and 1 thread does it slow.. any idea ?

Comment: Thanks @GustavoVargas , any idea to dont use index.dat ? $_SESSIONS ? or Mysql ? whats the best for the speed

Comment: As @GustavoVargas said, you'll need to make each thread read a subset of lines from the file. For example, let's assume the file has 200 lines and you want to divide the workload among 4 threads. In this case each thread would process 50 lines. Thread 1 would start at Line 1 and stop at line 50, thread 2 from 51 to 100 and so and so on.